# Combine Javascript files without erasing inline js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have finally managed to combine all my WordPress Javascript from my theme and plugins into a single bundle using the function below:

```
function merge_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    $wp_scripts -> all_deps($wp_scripts -> queue);
    
    $merged_file_location = get_stylesheet_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'merged-script.js';
    $merged_script  = '';
    
    foreach( $wp_scripts->to_do as $handle) {
        $src = strtok($wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src, '?');

        if (strpos($src, 'http') !== false) {
            $site_url = site_url();

            if (strpos($src, $site_url) !== false) $js_file_path = str_replace($site_url, '', $src);
            else $js_file_path = $src;

            $js_file_path = ltrim($js_file_path, '/');
        } else {            
            $js_file_path = ltrim($src, '/');
        }

        if  (file_exists($js_file_path)) {
            $localize = '';

            if (@key_exists('data', $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->extra)) {
                $localize = $obj->extra['data'] . ';';
            }

            $merged_script .=  $localize . file_get_contents($js_file_path) . ';';
        }
    }

    file_put_contents ( $merged_file_location , $merged_script);
    wp_enqueue_script('merged-script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/merged-script.js', array(), '1.0', false );

    foreach( $wp_scripts->to_do as $handle ) {
        wp_deregister_script($handle);
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'merge_all_scripts', 99 );
```

Problem is it erases all inline woocommerce js defined in the "get_script_data" woocommerce function. **I want it to include that aswell.**

Otherwise content such as this will not get injected into the DOM, and therefore prevent the site from working properly:

```
var wc_add_to_cart_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","wc_ajax_url":"\/?wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%","i18n_view_cart":"Se kurv","cart_url":"https:\/\/lawrence.dk\/bag\/","is_cart":"","cart_redirect_after_add":"no"};
```

Comment: I don’t know what your problem is, but calling `file_put_contents` on ever page load to the same file seems unnecessary and should be cacheable using the version parts.

Comment: How would you fix that?

Comment: Personally I use WP Rocket because it does this and so much more. But one way would be to inspect the version on each (`->ver`, I think) and build a master hash of all of them and keep that in a transient, and write your file as <hash>.js. When the hash changes, perform your combination logic and update the transient. Write to a dedicated folder, too, so that cleanup is easier. Also add an admin button to purge the cache, too.